# Need to update place of item in nested list python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have this nested list. The item at `[0][0]` is special and called `"h"`. I'd like `"h"` to be updated so it gives the illusion that it "moves" across the lists from **one** item to the other at a time (example, it could move from `[0][0]` to `[0][1]`, then from `[0][1]` to `[1][1]`, but not from `[1][1]` to `[3][5]`) 
I'm trying to build a function that would do the job for any possible pair of numbers in my nested list (6 lists of 6 items, so the max would be [6][6])
However, I can't find a way to put a "neutral item" in my function. I've tried something like this (so it goes from `[0][0]` to `[0][1]` etc):

```
for sublist in list:
        for item in sublist:
            h=list[n][n+1]
```

so that wherever h is, the function updates its position accordingly. But Python tells me that *n* cannot be used because it's a string.

What could I potentially do? Is a function the right tool? Should I use something else?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. You have to write a `for loop` and move the position of item from `[i][i]` to `[i][i+1]` and then `[i][i+1]` to `[i+1][i+1]`. Let's see with example. Initially our string is like this:

```
my_list = [['Here', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
```

And here is our loop:

```
for i in range(len(my_list) -1 ):
    my_list[i][i+1], my_list[i][i] = my_list[i][i], my_list[i][i+1]
    print 'New position --->', my_list
    my_list[i][i+1], my_list[i+1][i+1] = my_list[i+1][i+1], my_list[i][i+1]
    print 'New position --->', my_list
```

which will print the list in one line. For your clarity, I will illustrate it line 3x3 matrix.

```
#Initially, position = 0, 0
[['Here', '', ''], 
 ['', '', ''], 
 ['', '', '']]

# for i = 0, first print, position = 0, 1
[['', 'Here', ''], 
 ['', '', ''], 
 ['', '', '']]

# for i=0, second print, position = 1, 1
[['', '', ''], 
 ['', 'Here', ''], 
 ['', '', '']]

# for i=1, first print, position = 1, 2
[['', '', ''], 
 ['', '', 'Here'], 
 ['', '', '']]

# for i=1, second print, position = 2, 2
[['', '', ''], 
 ['', '', ''],
 ['', '', 'Here']]
```

Comment: Wow, well, yeah, I'm dumb, I should have thought about that. I always try to do stuff I don't know about and don't think about the simplest stuff... Anyway, thank you very much for your help !! Have a nice day !